# Trying to scroll to target ID on new tab load

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm trying to write a function that reads the URL, and if the URL contains a `#`, then the display jumps to the document element where `id=<string following #>`. So `myurl.com/#overview` should scroll to the document element where `id='overview'`.

I also want to run this function on page load after all document elements have loaded.

I've ran this function in the browser console, and it works. But when I run it on the `DOMContentLoaded` event, `target` is always `null`.

```
const mfn = function () {
  console.log('test');
  const url = window.location.href;
  const idIndex = url.indexOf('#');
  if (idIndex > -1) {
    const targetId = url.substr(idIndex + 1);
    console.log(targetId);
    const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    console.log(target);  // null :(
    target.scrollIntoView();
  }
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mfn);
```

Is there a better event to use?

**UPDATE:**
I realize this should be happening by default. For some reason, in my GatsbyJS blog, it's not happening. @Aaron Plocharczyk's answer's comments reveal a solution, but it's weird. Will ask in Gatbsy github issues.

Comment: isn't scroll to your target ID when add your ID in URL, Ex: `yourhost/#myid` ?

Comment: Just use anchor tags with `id` attributes. The `id` should be the same as the text after the hash in your link to said section. This is standard behavior in the `load_event`.

Comment: See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/barrychapman/82qcvkem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to write additional JavaScript to make the page jump to the element with the ID in the URL. It should already be doing that as default behavior, like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event#Examples. Is it possible that this element you're referring to is dynamically populated to that page at a later time through JavaScript DOM manipulation? If so, you'll need to call `mfn` *after* the element is added to the page. If you can't find where it's added to the page, try:

```
const url = window.location.href;
const idIndex = url.indexOf('#');
if(idIndex > -1){
    const targetId = url.substr(idIndex + 1);
    var elementLoadedCheck = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(targetId)){
            const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
            console.log(target);
            target.scrollIntoView();
            clearInterval(elementLoadedCheck);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

It's also possible you could've mistyped the ID.

Comment: https://welcometosoftware.com/what-is-an-api/#overview ... not sure why it won't work :(

Comment: It is using Gatsby which uses React... not sure if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

in my sample server I have two files, `index.html`, `test.html`

I ran a server using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which serve those two files,

`http-server .`

when I click the links in index file, the `test.html` opens in new tab and scroll to relevant ID.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <header>    
    </header>
    <body>
        <a href="/test.html#two" target"blank">two</a>
        <a href="/test.html#three" target"blank">three</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <header>    
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="one" style="height:100vh; background:red"> </div>
        <div id="two" style="height:100vh; background:green"> </div>
        <div id="three" style="height:100vh; background:yellow"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior, it will not require additional JavaScript.

If you want to `animate` the scroll, then that may (possibly?) be done with CSS transitions. Or you can use JS.

At any rate, the basic behavior is displayed on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/barrychapman/82qcvkem/